# Como montar um SELECT com coluna numérica inexistente ordenada

Tags: postgresql, select

Quero fazer um SELECT com algumas colunas já existentes no banco de dados e adicionar uma **coluna numérica ordenada começando em 1** para cada linha (não quero o ID). Estou usando PostgreSQL 8.4.

**Exemplo:**

```
SELECT 
    descricao_produto, 
    preco,
    colunaDinamicaOrdenada AS ordem
FROM produtos;
```

Onde `colunaDinamicaOrdenada` seria um comando, subselect ou algo do tipo que forme uma sequência de números ordenados começando em 1.

**Resultado desejado:**

```
descricao_produto | preco | ordem
Maçã                5,90    1
Banana              4,00    2
Melancia            7,00    3
Laranja             3,00    4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a função [row_number()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html)

```
SELECT 
    descricao_produto, 
    preco,
    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY descricao_produto) AS ordem
FROM produtos;
```

Comment: Cara esse `row_number()` era o que eu precisava pra fazer isso e acabou me ajudando MUITO em outros comandos que eu precisei fazer em seguida, valeu! Nem sabia da existencia dessas `window functions`

Answer (score 2):

Fala Edson! Não entendi bem se vc quer um contador ou um "ranking". Para um contador basta setar uma váriavel e adicionar no select:

```
SET @colunaDinamicaOrdenada:=0;
SELECT descricao_produto, preco,
@colunaDinamicaOrdenada:=@colunaDinamicaOrdenada+1 AS ordem
FROM produtos;
```

Agora se vc quiser fazer um ranking. Ai vai ter que fazer um count e agrupar as colunas (ou a que vc quer rankear). Exemplo:

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, descricao_produto, preço, COUNT(*) as       ordercount
 FROM produtos
 GROUP BY  descricao_produto, preço
 ORDER BY ordercount DESC;
```

Comment: Não funciona no Postgresql.